# Complexity of Symbolic sum in sympy

Tags: scipy, sum, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm using symbolic sum in sympy. I think the intermediate steps take huge memory. Can someone tell me the space and time complexity of the symbolic sum?

Comment: It is not clear if you are referring to the `sum`, `Sum`, `summation` etc functions as these are all different. It isn't possible to answer this question without more detail about the expressions and without knowing exactly what functions you are using. Most likely there is a faster way to do whatever you're doing. Show minimal self-contained code if you want a better answer.

Comment: Using Sum function. For example, Sum(f, (x, 0, 10)).doit(), where f is a polynomial function of n variables. The function is in its factorized form. For example, f(x,y)=(x+15y)*(2x+y)

Comment: Complexity is a concept used with numeric calculations, typically relating the number of "elements" to the calculation time.  I'm not sure it is used with computer algebra system (CAS).  CAS processing is not as simple and predictable.  There are a lot of heuristics, try-this-then-try-that kind of attempts.  Even memory use is not as clear cut.  The original CAS were written in LISP, with a very different memory use than numeric array packages like `numpy`.

Comment: In general `Sum.doit` uses a range of different algorithms so it's not easy to say what the complexity is in either time or memory without a precise example. Your example `Sum(f, (x, 0, 10)).doit()` does not take much time or memory though so I guess it is not actually the case you are interested in.

Comment: I'm not using it for just one function. I'm using it for a class of multivariable polynomial functions. It can have like thousand variables. I'm not expecting exact answer here. A ball park estimate will do just fine. I just need to know how the number of steps and memory grows as the number of variables grow. The bounds are constant here. Let's say from a to b for all variables. (Or atleast knowing whether or not time/space complexity become exponential will also help)